# Finding isomorph sub-graph with minimum (edge) weight

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, subgraph, isomorphism

I have an undirected graph *G* with edge weights and want to find a sub-graph that is isomorph to some other given graph *H*, such that the sum of all edge weights in the sub-graph is minimal. *H* is undirected as well but doesn't have any edge weights and can be disconnected.

- Is there an algorithm to find the minimal sub-graph?
- If *G* is a fully connected graph, does that simplify the problem?
- Follow-up: what if *H* also has edge weights and the goal is to minimize the sum of *f(w<sub>H</sub>, w<sub>G</sub>)* for some function *f* of the weights of an edge in *H* and its corresponding edge in the sub-graph of *G*

Comment: 1. Yes, but with no restrictions on H, it's gonna be slow. 2. Not really. 3. This makes the problem even harder.

Comment: 1. Do you have any reference to an algorithm? What restrictions would make it faster? In my practical use case the number of vertices in G and H would be the same and in the order of O(100)

Comment: You can make the problem easier by requiring that the graphs have anchor vertices. Anchor vertices are a set of vertices in a graph such that each vertex has degree greater than some minimum, and the cardinality of the set is small compared to the number of vertices in the graph. For example G has only 10 vertices with degree greater than 8, and H has only 5 such vertices. Then there are not more than 10C5 = 252 ways to map the anchor vertices.

Comment: Brute force is an algorithm. We can take H to be a clique, so this is at least as hard as clique finding.

Comment: To be less negative, there may be some tricks that we can play, but they're going to be data-dependent. If you can post representative samples of your graphs, that would probably help whoever takes a stab at answering this question (probably not me).

Comment: It might be good to give more details and especially define what you consider reasonably fast as all algorithms to do this will probably still be exponential as n choose k is theta(n^k).

Comment: "reasonably fast algorithm": you mean with polynomial complexity? Only these algotihms are reasonably fast. "that solves the problem": you mean optimally? Even without the constraint that "the sum of all edge weights in the sub-graph is minimal", the problem you describe is NP-complete. So, it is not possible to find a reasonably fast algorithm that solves the problem optimally.

Comment: Check out for question 1. Ullmann algorithm and 3. VF2 Algorithm (would need modifications to handle weights)

Comment: When H is a cycle of same number of vertices as G, this is the travelling salesman problem.

Comment: If, as you mentioned, in your case the number of vertices of G and H are equivalent, then aren't you simply checking whether they are isomorphic or not?